# How to view floating-point image on the web asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, floating-point

Is there any way to display floating point image on web form?

Alternatively, I would like to search for an algorithm to convert floating point image into a PNG or JPEG format.

I am looking for an open source project.

Comment: Related SO thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694739/convert-floating-point-rgba-bitmap-to-standard-dotnet-bitmap

Comment: Close recommended: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends very much on the format of the floating point imagery.

If you have straight uncompressed RGBA floats you can simply iterate over them using unsafe methods to clamp the float values to byte values and fill up the pixels of a dotnet bitmap which has been locked using the `lockbits` method.

For more information on `lockbits` see [this article by Bob Powell](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx).

If the floating point data is not uncompressed or not in a known or accessible format, you might try an open source library such as [FreeImage.NET](https://freeimage.sourceforge.io/) to open the image.